# Text in UITextField shift down and flash?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have iPhone5 device with iOS7. In application there is a custom `UITextField`. When I am editing it, the text shift down to bottom and flash. Even if I have set the vertical center constraint.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem in past. I don't know the exact solution But The following line of code works for me

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=NO;
```

hope it will works for you also

Comment: it works!!!! but why...I don't understand why the translucent property brings the trouble..

Comment: Actually it is the case that you are having the translucent  navigation bar on storyboard & you are pushing the view controller so it will create the default navigation bar that's why it will leave 64 pixels for translucent property

Comment: @seguedestination please accept this answer so that, this would be useful for  others also